# Append Custom list comments from email

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I'm trying to setup a form of email piping in SharePoint online for my helpdesk ticket system (custom list).

i.e. if a user replies to an email from my workflow to advise a ticket has been raised, I would like the contents of the reply email to be appended to the comments of the list item.

I'm expecting that the subject line of the email contains the unique identifier. i.e. ServiceRef:[ID] (where ID is the list item number i.e. ticket number).

I've started creating a flow, when a new email arrives and using an action of update item but my first issue is that I don't know how to define my list ID as there doesn't appear to be any dynamic content to choose the list ID number from.

My second issue is that the update item action doesn't have any comments fields.

I'm still quite new to flow so perhaps i've missed something or perhaps not possible with comments?

Anyone help?

Comment: Slight progress i think.  I'm now thinking I need to add a flow action, I think I should be using get items action to get the list of tickets using the filter query filtering by ID.  Though not sure how to match the serviceref: [ID] value with the list item ID field.

Comment: can you please specify which flow did you take from the list ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying quizhead, I have managed to resolve this myself with some help from a MVP. He showed me how to use the split expression to get the ServieRef ID number I needed from the email subject field.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this myself with some help from a MVP. I used the compose action to split the ServieRef ID number from the email subject field.

Comment: Hey, can you share your flow as I'm stuck in same situation and not sure how to do this.